# Powershell: export-csv file lastwitename

Tags: powershell

I am using the following code to export a list of file's lastwritetime into a csv file

LS c:\somepath | select name, lastwritetime | export-csv C:\x.csv

**How can I set a filter and exclude all folders or some file types.**

Thanks

**Update**

I tried where {$_.extension -eq ".zip"}  but it returns nothing

Comment: where {$_.extension -eq ".zip"} ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll address your 2 requirements one at a time. I'll start with excluding folders. Depending on the version of PowerShell you are using this could be very simple. If you are using v3 or higher you can simply use the -Files switch to exclude folders. It would be done as such:

```
LS C:\somefolder -files | select Name, LastWriteTime | export-csv c:\path\file.csv -notype
```

If you are using v2 or earlier you would need to filter after the directory listing is already pulled with a Where statement (I use the shortened term ?{} instead of Where{}).

```
LS C:\somefolder | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select Name, LastWriteTime | Export-CSV c:\path\file.csv -notype
```

Next, for excluding .Zip files you can exclude things with the -Exclude parameter. You want to list things in a comma delimited string, such as "*.Zip,*.7z,*.rar" which would exclude Zip, 7z, and Rar archives. You would do so as such:

```
gci C:\somefolder -Exclude "*.zip" | Select Name, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv C:\path\file.csv -notype
```

So to put that all together you would do something like:

```
gci C:\somefolder -Exclude "*.zip" | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Select Name, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv C:\path\file.csv -notype
```

Answer (score 0):

How about **-exlude**:

```
ls c:\somepath -exclude *.zip | select name, lastwritetime | export-csv C:\x.csv
```

By the way **ls** is an alias for [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)

Comment: Will this exclude *archive? folders

Comment: The example I have given will exclude files which end .zip